# Shortcuts not working after upgrading Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, shortcut-keys, 20.04, shortcuts, do-release-upgrade

I recently upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 an now I am seeing that over desktop none of the shortcut keys is working such as CTRL+C CTRL+V SHIFT+DEL. Though I am able to able to perform above using the mouse. Apart from these, I checked my gnome version and it upgraded to the newest version.

After looking at the internet, I also tried to replace Nautilus to Nemo or Nemo to Nautilus but none of these is working.

Could any please help me out with clear steps? This is really frustrating...